# How to update a perticular area on a page without using Ajax or Update Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Update Panel or Ajax  is not supported by my server,Is there any alternative using jquery or javascript or any else to update a perticular area on page?
like a dropdown list control on asp.net page

Comment: If you are not going to interact with server its possible using .html()

Comment: But can't we do this with with jquery/Javascript?

Comment: Its indeed a jquery function http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to UpdatePanels - PageMethods. It is a combination of jQuery and jQuery templates and faster than UpdatePanels. You can also check the following link

http://encosia.com/use-jquery-and-aspnet-ajax-to-build-a-client-side-repeater/